# BVP in R: how to get a numerical solution?

Tags: r, differential-equations

Good day to you all :)

I'm need some help with the boundary value problem.

This is my equation:

sin(1)*y'' + (1+cos(1)*x^2)*y = -1

-1 < x < 1

y(-1) = y(1) = 0

And I'd like to solve this equation by built-in method.

So, I asked the same question on Maple forum (https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/225225-Dsolve-Does-Not-Work-solving-A-Boundary-Value-Problem) and there is no build-in method.

> Maple have No  built-in collocation methods, least squares method,  Galerkin method to solve ode's.
>   dsolve it have method `series`,but in your case dosen't work.

After that, I decided to try to solve this equation with R.

```html
library('bvpSolve')

fun <- function(x,y,pars) {
  d1 = sin(1)*y[2]
  d2 = -1 - (1 + cos(1))*y[1]
  return(list(c(d1, d2)))
}

init = c(y = 0, dy = NA)
end = c(y = 0, dy = NA)

sol = bvpcol(yini = init, x = seq(-1, 1, 0.01), 
              func = fun, yend = end, parms = NULL)
x = sol[, 1]
y = sol[, 2]
plot(x, y, type = "l")
```

It builds graphs (probably correct) (at least they match the graphs in Maple)), but I still can't get the numerical solution.

I'd like to get the same result (http://fredrik-j.blogspot.com/2009/02/galerkins-method-in-sympy.html), but in R.

I'd be very grateful if you could suggest some built-in numerical R methods that would help solve this equation.

I don't realy think it's a good idea to explicitly interpolate the function result (as suggested by the Maple community).Is there a simple and effective way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "but I still can't get the numerical solution"? `y` is the numerical solution.

Comment: I would like to get the result in polynomial form, but without explicit interpolation.
Like that:
http://fredrik-j.blogspot.com/2009/02/galerkins-method-in-sympy.html

Comment: I think you'll need to implement something yourself.